# How to improve query performance if runs against view spanning over more than 50 tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I have a bit situation with SSRS reports which I have built and currently under development.

Some background on DB. We have CRM on-prem2015, which has SQL DB in the back end. My SSRS reports are based on Filtered Views, which has matching names in the front-end in CRM. So I have to pick and choose the field from the filtered view and then put the SQL logic in.

Since mostly reports are based on new Admission and Service Activities view, which has 1-N relationship respectively. Both this views are growing exponentially day by day.

If I just run `Select * from ServiceActivitesFilteredView` it takes more than 15 minutes to return around 500,000 rows which i growing by 2000 a day. This view is based on more than 50 tables, mostly I checked those are connected in the back end with Left Outer Join.

And If I just run `Select * from AdmissionFileteredView` it takes around 7 minutes and growing I would say day by day and returns around 215,000 rows.

So when I have to make any reports via including both above FilteredViews it is becoming nightmare. There are two situation though!

1. If I put too many parameters in SSRS and try to drill down to client level( Most granular level) which is either one or few rows as result, SSRS report works fine.
2. But when reports need data at Office level or Area level which may have few hundreds clients it's started taking more than 20 minutes to return the results with depending on the office( see blow code, but no more than 100 rows).

I have created ODS for few reports where it was OK to have one-day or one-week old data. But few reports needs live data and which are getting very poor in performance day by day. I tried `"SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;"` and also "with(nolock)" option in stored procedure where I use this views. Just FYI. we are not ready at this point to go DataWarehouse side.

Here is the stored procedure which forced me to ask this question on this forum. Basically, our company has policy that Supervisor will go to client house who has agreed to install Air conditioner services, Supervisor will go on the day installers will install the AC. What I am trying to do here is to get list of clients who missed Initial Visit from supervisor when they installed Air conditioner from our company, and next booked or reschedule service date for the same client so that installed can go with them and finish their Initial visit as mentioned in policy.

```
Select data.ServiceproviderName,data.new_clientidname,data.new_subprogramname,data.createdon,data.new_addresscity,data.new_workgroupidname,nextdate.NextVisitdate,data.new_sitename from 

        (Select distinct

            fa.new_sitename,
            fa.new_clientidname,
            fs.new_subprogramname,
            fa.new_servicename,
            fa.createdon,
            fa.new_admissionid,
            fa.ServiceproviderName,
            fa.new_addresscity,
            fa.new_workgroupidname

        from AdmissionFilteredView fa with(nolock)
        left join ServiceAppoinmentFilteredView fs with(nolock)
        on
        fa.new_admissionid=fs.regardingobjectid

        where 
        fa.new_sitename IN (SELECT value FROM dbo.udf_Split(@Office, ','))
        and cast(fa.createdon as date) BETWEEN cast(@Start as date) AND cast(@End as date)
        and fa.new_admissionstatusname In ('Admitted')
        and fa.new_servicename like 'AC Repair%'
        and fs.new_visittypename <> 'Initial'

        group by
        fa.new_sitename,fa.new_clientidname,fa.new_admissionid,fa.new_servicename,fa.createdon,fs.new_subprogramname,fa.ServiceproviderName,fa.new_admissionid,fa.new_addresscity,fa.new_workgroupidname)  data

        left join
        (Select distinct new_clientidname,min(fs.scheduledstart) as NextVisitdate
        from
        AdmissionFilteredView fa with(nolock)
        left join ServiceAppoinmentFilteredView fs with(nolock)
        on
        fa.new_admissionid=fs.regardingobjectid
        where fa.new_sitename IN (SELECT value FROM dbo.udf_Split(@Office, ','))
        and cast(fa.createdon as date) BETWEEN cast(@Start as date) AND cast(@End as date)
        and fa.new_admissionstatusname In ('Admitted')
        and fa.new_servicename like 'AC Repair%'
        and fs.new_visittypename <> 'Initial'
        and fs.statuscodename IN ('Booked','Rescheduled')
        group by 
        new_clientidname) nextdate
        on data.new_clientidname=nextdate.new_clientidname
```

This takes roungly 25 minutes in SSMS and 35 minutes in SSRS in SSDT and it even doesn't run on the CRM and goes in SQL - time out error. I can't create ODS since this report needs the live data.

Only thing I can think of is to find actual tables from which these two views are created and re-write this stor. proc. based on these tables or create two tables from these two views and write a code to have up-to-date data in these tables ,I am not sure even this is possible by something like Change data capture or incremental load or update these two tables every time there is new entry in the views or tables which made these two views.

Please help, considering the bigger picture and not just this stored procedure in general.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129851/discussion-on-question-by-user2040021-how-to-improve-query-performance-if-runs-a).

Answer (score 1):

You can use snapshot option in ssrs ,so report will not keep on loading at client end .
At database end ,have you tried creating indexes on your tables ??

Comment: Well I just ran execution plan and it cam up with recommendation of creating non-clustered index in one of the two views. Since it's CRM DB it's very maintained with our maintenance plan of keeping the indexes in very good condition.

Comment: create two separate reports

Comment: That's for sure will speed up the things but I am not sure that they gonna like it.

Comment: one with current hour data and one with all previous hours data ,except current hour .and merge these two reports using subreport in ssrs .put previous hours data on snapshot in ssrs, as i believe previous hours data wont change .this will work as warehouse concept.

Comment: you can do it till you move on to warehouse solution.or anyother better solution

Comment: Hey @tahreen, this would be the ideal solution for now, Thanks for this. Could you please share on how to move on this, or where to find related information to go on this route? or what to do you call this process? Mirroring or replication or something? Any info on how to get this done would be great!

Comment: make 2 copies of your report file .filter your queries based on above condition.then host both reports on server ,go to manage report and then processing option put one report on snapshot. in second report call sub report which you put on snapshot plus current hour data

Comment: Excellent! Thanks @Tahreen Saeed

Comment: Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: But i would recommend ,move to data warehouse as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments regarding your split function. You could store that overhead in a table variable, and the just reference the variable in your query:

```
DECLARE @Start DATETIME, @End DATETIME 
;

DECLARE @office VARCHAR(123) = 'Office A,Office B,Office C'
;

DECLARE @officeList TABLE ( 
    Office VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO @officeList
SELECT Value FROM dbo.udf_Split(@office, ',')
;

DECLARE @local_StartDate DATE = cast(@Start as date), 
        @local_EndDate DATE = cast(@End as date);

-- from your query
where 
    fa.new_sitename IN (SELECT Office FROM @officeList)
    and cast(fa.createdon as date) BETWEEN @local_StartDate AND @local_EndDate
```

Comment: I will just allow user to select one office at a time so I can take out that function completely and just put like fa.new_sitename = @site

Answer (score 1):

1. Create snapshot of the database which is also called reporting database. You can do hourly snapshot or weekly depending upon the frequency of reports.
2. Run reports as task on background thread:- You can create jobs that run at night, that will create reports for you by querying reporting database and will present you a report when you come in morning. Or you can create it as a task that runs on background and sends you an email when report is ready so you do not have to wait 15 minutes for report to be generated.
3. Use non-clustered indexes/Filtered indexes for columns you are returning and using in where clauses.
4. You can create a new table and insert the reporting data query that you have into that at night and then just do select * from new table to get a report which would be very fast because data will already build at night.

If you cannot improve your query and data is increasing every day, then snapshot/reporting database is your best bet.

Comment: Thanks @Nirjhar, but I believe I can't use snapshot option since I have SE of SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Why don't you pre-execute the queries and store it in a new table. Create a job/program that runs at night and run this query and store all the results in new table. Then your report should query from new table. Option 4 @user2040021

Comment: What will happen in this case is Manager will have "Till yesterday's Data" , and they will start making call to go and see the client based on next available visit date, which might be booked by the time she calls and next visit may be available after few weeks!! I hope I didn't make confusion here via explaining business process!

Comment: @user2040021 I thought this was just a report, not a booking system?
You should run your booking process on reports.

Comment: No this is not a booking system, but you can get information about the client who missed that initial visit and then you can go in CRM and book the visit with that client.

Comment: Then you can store data in different table hourly rather than daily so your data will be more up to date @user2040021

Comment: I agree with you but when I load the data again in that table it will take another 10-14 minutes before I load that data, I have to drop that table which has one hour old data, what happens if someone tries to run that report during that 10-14 minutes?

Comment: You should not drop the table and add the data. You should write queries to find data that was changed and new data inserted. Only add or update the new data to table. That should only take seconds. @user2040021

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129824/discussion-between-user2040021-and-nirjhar-vermani).

Answer (score 1):

How often do you need to run the report and how concurrent does it need to be?  Would the users be ok with near-real time data vs. real time data?  Perhaps you could pre-execute the heavy queries with a sql job and store the results in staging tables and then report off of the staging table or a combination of staging tables.   Perhaps some of the 50 operational tables could be warehoused into dimensional tables or staging tables designed for reporting.  Also, what version of SQL Server are you using?  It will help us figure out what might be available in your bag of tricks.

Comment: Not very often! may be once a week by every manager but it has to live or near to the real time dat may be I would say 2-hours old should be ok! Can you please share some info on how to pre-execute heavy queries and store into staging tables, do you mean SSAS cubes? I am using Standard edition of 2012.

Comment: I think the comment from Nirjhar is what I had in mind.  Set up a SQL Job to run your performance tuned query/sproc and insert the results into a table that would be refreshed once per night or week at around the time the data was needed.  I was not thinking of the SSAS cubes, I was thinking you might just set up a table that has your pre-queried results or set up some tables with a dimensional model.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I noticed was you have 'select distinct' right at the top. This type of statement locks up tables and negates use of with no lock, and left join.

You need to re-write your queries so they do NOT use any 'select distinct' clauses.